# Clear all activities

Tags: android, stack, back

I have 4 activities: A, B, C and D. And one more: E.

Thre is no problem when y start a new activity between A, B, C and D. But in some points of these (for example, when a login is successful) we want to start activity E but clear all A, B, C and D activities (that is, clearing the back stack).

So, I want when yoy arrive to activity E, and press the back button, you will leave of the application.

I am trying do it adding flags in the startActivity: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and some more, but I can't achieve the behaviour.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                this.startActivity(intent);
                this.finish();
```

Comment: That isn't working for me. Finally, the solution is BroadcastReeiver, in order to achieve the login/logout structure I want.

Comment: used setFlag() insted of addFlag() like this intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed in activity E as

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try as for `startActivity` Activity A,B,C and E

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
A.this.finish();
```

and declare your A,B and C activity as in `androidmanifest.xml` :

```
<Activity android:name=".A" 
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
 //..do B,C activities same
```

and override onKeyDown in Activity E

```
@verride
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        Activity_E.this.finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Good idea! But the problem is that I want a specific behaviour like this: if I've not arrived to activity E yet, I want the user can back to another activity, so I can't finish them until I stay en Activity E. I don't know if you understand me. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @alberking : i understand u dear. just use an String flag in which u can store current activity name and send it with intent when you are starting new Activity. in new Activity check for from which Activity user is coming before calling Activity.this.finish() or on backpressed if user is inside E Activity then finish E Activity on back press , if user is inside activity D then on backpressed start C activity ....